# How To Queue Files for Upload at a Later time/different page

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, plupload

I am developing a cart (utilizing OpenCart).  The cart allows people to order prints of images. Because the images will be high resolution and therefore large files, I need a method that allows the following:

1. The customer arrives at a product page,
2. The customer selects an image for the product,
3. The file does NOT upload at that time (or, begins uploading in the background),
4. Without waiting for the file upload, the customer adds the product to the cart,
5. Repeat steps 1-4 as needed for additional products (and image files),
6. AFTER successful checkout, the files are uploaded (or, they complete uploading)

It seems the key is to put the files into a queue, and for that queue to persist across page loads until completion of the order.

I'm familiar with [PLupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and have found [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), but do not see in their documentation how to accomplish what I'm after.

Can you get me pointed in the right direction? I'm sure this is doable, I'm just unsure how to get started and am unable to find any writeups/documentation around this specific issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using AJAX for all state changes, you can't "remember" a file upload input and repopulate it. (When using AJAX you could hide the forms). You can either let the user upload files right before checkout (not a good practice) or let the user upload in a popup and have the popup use AJAX so you can add forms on the fly as soon as new items are added to the cart.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming it would involve AJAX.  Just don't quite know how you can store a "pointer" to a file on the client computer via AJAX and call it later.  Popups are not an option.

Comment: Quite simply, you are not allowed to ever change the website (but with AJAX requests). If it would be different, how would you know the user actually still wants to upload the files you "saved". Not securing this could lead to unlimited read access to any client machine.